# Button to remove first div and slide the adjacent div to its position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have been breaking my head over this. 
I know it's fairly easy to implement to do this but i can't seem to get my head around it.
Have a look at this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/G9x8V/

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').on('click', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).parents('.outer-box').hide(1000);
        });

    });
});
```

Now how do i add a button to hide a the first div and slide the rest of the div to move to the first position.

http://jsfiddle.net/L12yte6r/

```
$(function(){
    $('.button').on('click', function(){
        $('.box').fadeOut(1000, function(){

        });

    });
});
```

I have updated the above code with the button in the above fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give all the `div` the same generic class
2. Create a "*hidden*" class to style the hidden `div`
3. Select the `first()` `div` having the same generic class without the "*hidden*" class
4. Apply the "*hidden*" class to it

***See this snippet:***

```js
$(function () {
    $('.button').on('click', function () {
        $(".outer-box1").not(".hidden").first().addClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
.container { width: 400px; }
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
.outer-box1 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    float: left;
    opacity: 1;         /* to display:none won't allow transition animation */
    overflow: hidden;   /* to prevent children to overflow when size is 0 */
    transition: 1s all; /* to animate the effects */
}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;  /* to hide without display:none to allow transition */
    width: 0px;  /* effectively hide by reducing size and allow transition */
    margin: 0px; /* to properly align rest of the divs */
}
button {
    margin: 4px; /* just to separate button from divs */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer-box1"><div class="box">1</div></div>
    <div class="outer-box1"><div class="box">2</div></div>
    <div class="outer-box1"><div class="box">3</div></div>
    <div class="outer-box1"><div class="box">4</div></div>
</div>
<button class="button">Click</button>
```

***Here is a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/L12yte6r/5/***

---

### Update:

Instead of hiding and sliding together, if you are wanting to wait before sliding the divs, you need to chain the transitions. See this snippet, where it first hides then waits and then slides the rest of the divs.

Note the only change is in the transition:

*Instead of*:

```
transition: 1s all;
```

*it now becomes*:

```
transition: opacity 1000ms, 
    width 500ms linear 1000ms, 
    margin 500ms linear 1000ms;
```

***See the snippet below***:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.button').on('click', function () {
        $(".outer-box1").not(".hidden").first().addClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
.container { width: 600px; }
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
.outer-box1 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    float: left;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1000ms, 
        width 500ms linear 1000ms, 
        margin 500ms linear 1000ms;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

button {
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer-box1"><div class="box">1</div></div>
    <div class="outer-box1"><div class="box">2</div></div>
    <div class="outer-box1"><div class="box">3</div></div>
    <div class="outer-box1"><div class="box">4</div></div>
</div>
<button class="button">Click</button>
```

***Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/L12yte6r/11/***

Comment: Awesome! 
Is there a possibility to remove the first box and move the other divs to their place

Comment: what i meant is after using the remove function.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
<style>
.container {
    width: 600px;
}
.box {
    width: 20%;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
   $('.box:visible').first().fadeOut(1000, function(){

    });

    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L12yte6r/4/

Comment: this will only work for the first box and not if you want to hide more then one box one after another

Comment: use this
$('.box:visible').first().fadeOut(1000, function(){
           
        });

Comment: Yeah, but the other divs need to slide to the first position. Right now its abrupt. Is it possible to make it smooth?

Comment: for this you have to use animate function try it. :)

Comment: I tried doing that initially but it didn't seem to work.
   animated the second div by enforcing the left and toggling the slide function on it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/L12yte6r/5/

This jdfiddle hides the first div and then moves the other divs subsequently. But I want to remove the class and subclasses because the classes already have a css parameter with important marked on them. I hope i made sense